# Create a new column from results in Folium

Tags: python, grouping, coordinates, folium

I have been working with an Accident Database from Seattle which contains the coordinates of around 200,000 accidents. What I want to do is to group those accidents geographically in districts, for example. To that end I visualised the grouping on a map using Folium but now I don't know how to extract those same groups into a new column in my database (or if it is even possible).

Here is what I have been doing with Folium and the result:

```
from folium import plugins
#Using Seattle's latitude and longitude 
latitude = 47.608013 
longitude = -122.335167


seattle_map = folium.Map(location = [latitude, longitude], zoom_start = 12)

incidents = plugins.MarkerCluster().add_to(seattle_map)

for lat, lng, label, in zip(database.Y, database.X, database.SEVERITYCODE):
    folium.Marker(
        location=[lat, lng],
        icon=None,
        popup=folium.Popup(label),
    ).add_to(incidents)

seattle_map
```

[Output Folium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wi5RX.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the districts of Seattle, you can use this Github repository with all kinds of geographical data about Seattle : https://github.com/seattleio/seattle-boundaries-data

For instance, if you want to add the zipcode areas on the map, you can use the geojson file like this :

```
latitude = 47.608013 
longitude = -122.335167

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seattleio/seattle-boundaries-data/master/data/zip-codes.geojson"

seattle_map = folium.Map(location = [latitude, longitude], zoom_start = 12)
folium.GeoJson(
    url,
    name='zip_code'
).add_to(seattle_map)

seattle_map
```

If you want to add the zipcode areas to the collisions data, the best is to use Choropleth map from Folium. You need to work a little on your data to know to which zipcode area belongs the collision. I use the shapely library to do so. You can create a code like that :

```
import json
import requests
import folium
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import shape, Point

# Url of the geojson with zipcode of Seattle
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/seattleio/seattle-boundaries-data/master/data/zip-codes.geojson"
# Import data of the collisions in Seattle
df = pd.read_csv("Collisions.csv")
# Keep only lat and long
df_clean = df.loc[:, ["X", "Y"]]
df_clean = df_clean.dropna()

r = requests.get(url)
for index,row in df_clean.iterrows():
    for feature in r.json()["features"]:
        polygon = shape(feature['geometry'])
        point = Point(row[0], row[1])
        if polygon.contains(point):
            df_clean.loc[index,'ZCTA5CE10'] = feature["properties"]['ZCTA5CE10']
            break
            
df_clean = df_clean.dropna()
result = df_clean.groupby(["ZCTA5CE10"])["X"].count()
result = pd.DataFrame(result)
result.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

#Using Seattle's latitude and longitude 
latitude = 47.608013 
longitude = -122.335167

seattle_map = folium.Map(location = [latitude, longitude], zoom_start = 12)
folium.Choropleth(
 geo_data=url,
 name='choropleth',
 data=result,
 columns=["ZCTA5CE10", 'X'],
 key_on='feature.properties.ZCTA5CE10',
 fill_color='YlOrRd',
).add_to(seattle_map)

seattle_map
```

You can improve a lot my code in terms of performance (it is clearly not the best choice to use a for loop to create a new column of the dataframe)